Markdown file preview not show anything in Android Studio
My Android Studio is lastest version (Android Studio Jellyfish). I installed the markdown plugin and set up "Choose Boot Java Runtime for IDE..." but the preview tab only shows a blank screen.
Markdown preview issue

What Java runtime did you choose? Some versions come with no JCEF (embedded browser). Therefore, MD preview cannot work with it.

I am using latest JCEF version (17.0.10+1-1087.23-jcef).

Are there any related errors/warnings in log ("Help | Show log in...")?

I also got this issue and finally find the solution.
After set up "Choose Boot Java Runtime for IDE..." to the newest version.
The registry setting about ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable should be disabled.

You can also check the setting steps in this link.(Answer #61)

yess, its work!

see https://joachimschuster.de/posts/android-studio-fix-markdown-plugin/
